# Is it possible to do performance testing on application using Corba protocol through JMeter?

Tags: performance-testing, corba

My client's application major parts runs on CORBA protocol and rest on HTTP.
The Corba protocol generate specific IOR which remain undetected by Jmeter on re-run and throws error. How could we parameterize and what approach should be followed?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), check out the following material for more information:

- [CORBA Technology and the Java Platform Standard Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/corba.html)
- [CORBA RMI Example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/java.816/a81356/appcorb4.htm)
- [CORBA IDL Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExample.html)

---

If you have existing Unit or Integration tests written using [JUnit framework](https://junit.org/) you can replay them with increased number of threads using [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler.

Comment: I don't have the JUnit framework available to work on. Thanks for the links and information. But I am totally unaware how to handle IOR through groovy because it has no content. If you could please help in this.